# AKMetronome class in Swift / iOS implemenation

Tags: audiokit

I'm working on a parametrization of functional harmony (for my students at UdK berlin). I'd like to use the AKMetronome to run through some of the generated sequences in a regulated fashion.

I'm using the dynamic libraries for iOS (and using Swift) -- I don't seem to have access to the AKMetronome class... what am I missing?

I am still new with audiokit, but it seems installed right and is making sounds with the Oscillator. A metronome would vastly increase my ability to test harmony results by ear...

Thanks

Tim

Comment: I just tested and the AKMetronome seems accessible still. If you care to share you code in a Github repo, even privately (though better for SO if its public), I can have a closer look.

Comment: Thank your for this... I was referencing an older version I had -- an organization problem I'd been putting off and now must address... I am glad for all the work you've put in, the question arose from improperly investigated confusion.